# Can I insert values to a column according to a condition? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I was wondering how can I , for example, if I have:

```
Employees:  nameOfEmployee,numberOfEmployee,numberOfDepartment,....,....,....,....,...,....,....
Departments:  numberOfDepartment,numberOfEmployees,....,....,....,....,...,....,....
```

and there is already rows in the tables, fill the values in Departments.numberOfEmployees with the adding of nameOfEmployee

The only thing I came up with so far is this:

```
UPDATE Departments
SET numberOfEmployees=COUNT(Employees.nameOfEmployee)
FROM Employees
WHERE Departments.numberOfDepartment=Employees.numberOfDepartment
```

I know this probably won't even make any sence. I'm just getting started with SQL

Comment: You are persisting Aggregate data.  Most times, you don't want to do this.  Select dept.numberOfDepartment , [MyCount] = count(*) from Departments dept join Employees emps on dept.numberOfDepartment=emps.numberOfDepartment
Group By dept.numberOfDepartment

Comment: I tried this but It didn't work. I can't see how COUNT is actually counting the numbers of employees. Doesn't it has to be related to numberOfEmployees in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this **(UNTESTED)**

```
UPDATE Departments
SET numberOfEmployees=(SELECT COUNT(Employees.nameOfEmployee)
FROM Employees
WHERE Departments.numberOfDepartment=Employees.numberOfDepartment)
```

Comment: Awesome!It worked!Now I actually get how SELECT works. Thank u for your time!

Comment: glad i could help and you are welcom